# Retrieve Interface Class of a Proxy Invocation Object in Java

Tags: java, proxy-classes

I have an Interface whose implementation is deciding at Runtime and is given a Proxy Object as its dynamic implementation. I want to retrieve the Interface which this proxy object implements to know the methods in the interface. Is there any way I can do so in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (using plain reflection):

```
Class<?>[] interfaces = proxyInstance.getClass().getInterfaces();
```

For the following code:

```
Object proxyInstance = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    getClass().getClassLoader(), 
    new Class<?>[] {Serializable.class},
    new InvocationHandler() /**/);
```

It correctly return `java.io.Serializable` interface.